# Stop parsing on first unknown argument

Tags: python, argparse

Using [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/argparse.html), is it possible to stop parsing arguments at the first unknown argument?

I've found 2 almost solutions;

1. [`parse_known_args`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_known_args), but this allows for known parameters to be detected after the first unknown argument.
2. [`nargs=argparse.REMAINDER`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6488752/dont-parse-options-after-the-last-positional-argument/6671440#6671440), but this won't stop parsing until the first non-option argument. Any options preceding this that aren't recognised generate an error.

Have I overlooked something? Should I be using `argparse` at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used `argparse` myself (need to keep my code 2.6-compatible), but looking through the docs, I don't think you've missed anything.

So I have to wonder why you want `argparse` to stop parsing arguments, and why the `--` pseudo-argument won't do the job. [From the docs:](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#arguments-containing)

> If you have positional arguments that must begin with `'-'` and don’t look like negative numbers, you can insert the pseudo-argument `'--'` which tells `parse_args()` that everything after that is a positional argument:

```
>>> parser.parse_args(['--', '-f'])
Namespace(foo='-f', one=None)
```

Comment: This actually does the job. Thanks.

Comment: In my case, `--` won't do the job because I don't want to force my users to add `--` in their command in some cases and not in others :p

Comment: Then tell them to use it every time. Git strongly recommends using`--` before listing paths in `git checkout`, for example. Also, nobody is forcing you to always put it in; it’s just there for when arguments might be misinterpreted as options.

Comment: In the git checkout case, the "--" is necessary to disambiguate whether the argument is a tree-ish or a pathspec (unless both are provided). Furthermore, what if I want something like the `-c` option in bash or `-e` in xterm, where a flag indicates that all remaining arguments includeing ones that start with "-" should be used?

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it, although it may not be perfect in all situations, is to use `getopt` instead.

for example:

```py
import sys
import os
from getopt import getopt


flags, args = getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'hk', ['help', 'key='])

for flag, v in flags:
    if flag in ['-h', '--help']:
        print(USAGE, file=sys.stderr)
        os.exit()
    elif flag in ['-k', '--key']:
        key = v
```

Once `getopt` encounters a non-option argument it will stop processing arguments.